# Help with Lyx type problem

Tags: lyx

I am new to LaTeX and Lyx. I was typing my text when I changed something in Lyx and now, for example, I need to type two times dot (`.`) to show up at the display. If I type `dot + space`, it shows one of these points between " " ("  ̇ ̇ ̇ ̇ "); if I type `? + space`, it shows this:  " ° " .

In the code appears `\.{ }` in the first case and `\r{ }` in the second one.

How can I disable this automatic substitution of the code?

Comment: Strange. I haven't seen this happen in my use of LyX on Ubuntu. Which version of LyX are you using and what is your OS? Consider exiting LyX, renaming your home folder, `~/.lyx` to something else (to back it up), and restarting LyX (which will regenerate your home folder).

Comment: I'm using LyX 2.0.5 and my OS is windows 8. I mean that I type some shortcut command and now I can't use `dot + space` , `? + space`, `> + space`, `: + space` without change the characters.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? I don't know what the home folder is on Windows but you can see it in the Help > About menu. Consider upgrading. The bug you're seeing might have been fixed in a newer version.

Comment: I did not understand your suggestion, but now I understood and could fix the problem! Thank you. Also updated my lyx!

Comment: Great, glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

To reset your home folder (which contains shortcuts and preferences), just rename it (or delete it if you're sure you won't lose any precious settings). To find out what your home folder is, go to Help > About. On Linux it is `~/.lyx`.